# navigation fragment working in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a navigation drawer in that the navigation menu one option is profile ,whenever i try to click the profile an profile fragment activity in opened as I made the intent on that activity but the xml view of that activity is not visible at all. only blank screen appears with no background. can anyone help me out.

activity_profile_fragment.xml

```
                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.shubham.JeevanSathi.Activity.ProfileFragment"
                android:background="#FFF">



               <ScrollView
                   android:layout_width="368dp"
                   android:layout_height="495dp"
                   tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
                   tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                   >


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="368dp"
                    android:layout_height="495dp"

                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="110dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"


                        android:text="My Profile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="33sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"


                        android:text="My Profile"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                        android:textSize="32sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:typeface="sans" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_photo"
                        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:outlineProvider="bounds"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll1"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_photo"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                            android:text="Name:"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/age"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Age:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/religion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Religion:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/address"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Address:"

                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/zodiacsign"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Zodiac Sign:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dob"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Date of Birth:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bloddgroup"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Blood Group:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/fathername"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Father's Name:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mothername"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:text="Mother's Name:"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                           />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/sibling"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="No. of Siblings:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/height"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Height:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/weight"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Weight:"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/hobbies"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hobbies:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/complexion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="complexion:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/langknw"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Language Known:"

                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_photo"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disname"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="XYZ"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disage"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="23"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disreligion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="hindu"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disaddress"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="pune"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/diszodiacsign"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Aquarius"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disdob"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="10/02/1993"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disbloddgroup"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="B+"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disfathername"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="abc"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dismothername"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:text="pqr"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dissibling"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2 sisters"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disheight"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="5'11"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/disweight"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="63"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dishobbies"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Drawing"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/discomplexion"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Wheaty"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dislangknw"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Hindi, English, Gujrathi, Marathi"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:inputType="text"/>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>
               </ScrollView>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
                    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

                        private NavigationView navigationView;
                        private DrawerLayout drawer;
                        private View navHeader;
                        private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
                        private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
                        private Toolbar toolbar;
                        private FloatingActionButton fab;
                        ActionBar actionBar;
                        //This is our tablayout
                        private TabLayout tabLayout;

                        //This is our viewPager
                        private ViewPager viewPager;

                        // urls to load navigation header background image
                        // and profile image
                        private static final String urlNavHeaderBg = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/nav-menu-header-bg.jpg";
                        private static final String urlProfileImg = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/eCtE_G34M9ygdkmOpYvCag1vBARCmZwnVS6rS5t4JLzJ6QgQSBquM0nuTsCpLhYbKljoyS-txg";

                        // index to identify current nav menu item
                        public static int navItemIndex = 0;

                        // tags used to attach the fragments
                        private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
                        private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "profile";
                        private static final String TAG_MOVIES = "movies";
                        private static final String TAG_NOTIFICATIONS = "notifications";
                        private static final String TAG_SETTINGS = "settings";
                        public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

                        // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
                        private String[] activityTitles;

                        // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
                        private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
                        private Handler mHandler;

                        ArrayList<ToDoListPojo> arr;
                        ListView lst,lst1;
                        EditText edtTitle,edtDesc, tname,tdesc;
                        ToDoListAdapter tAdapter;
                        ImageView iv,iv1;

                        @Override
                        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                            Intent intent= getIntent();

                            //declarations for list view
                            arr = new ArrayList<>();
                            lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bride_list_view);
                            lst1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.groom_list_view);
                            edtTitle= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
                            edtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtDescription);
                            tname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                            tdesc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.desc);
                            iv= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
                            iv1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon1);
                            tAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(this,arr);
                            lst.setAdapter(tAdapter);


                            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                            actionBar.show();
                            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                            // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                            mHandler = new Handler();

                            drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

                            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

                            View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

                          //  fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

                            // Navigation view header
                            navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                            txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
                            txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
                            imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
                            imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

                            // load toolbar titles from string resources
                            activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);

                          /*  fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                                }
                            });*/

                            // load nav menu header data
                            loadNavHeader();

                            // initializing navigation menu
                            setUpNavigationView();

                            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                                navItemIndex = 0;
                                CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                                loadHomeFragment();
                            }

                             /*
                            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                    */

                            //Initializing the tablayout
                            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

                            //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Search Bride"));
                            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Search Groom"));
                            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

                            //Initializing viewPager
                          viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

                            //Creating our pager adapter
                            Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

                            //Adding adapter to pager
                            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
                            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


                                @Override
                                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                                    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(position, positionOffset, true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                                }

                                //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views

                                //tabLayout.setOnClickListener();


                            });
                        }


                        public void  addItem(View v)
                        {
                            String title = edtTitle.getText().toString();
                            String des = edtDesc.getText().toString();
                            String Tname = tname.getText().toString();
                            String Tdesc = tdesc.getText().toString();

                            ToDoListPojo t = new ToDoListPojo();
                            t.setTitle(title);
                            t.setDescription(des);
                            t.setTname(Tname);
                            t.setTdesc(Tdesc);


                            arr.add(t);
                            tAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        public void det(View view) {

                            Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,bio_data.class);

                            startActivity(i2);
                        }


                        /***
                         * Load navigation menu header information
                         * like background image, profile image
                         * name, website, notifications action view (dot)
                         */
                        private void loadNavHeader() {
                            // name, website
                            txtName.setText("shubham");
                            txtWebsite.setText("shubhamkanugo@gmail.com");

                            // loading header background image
                            Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                                    .crossFade()
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                    .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

                            // Loading profile image
                            Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                                    .crossFade()
                                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                                    .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                    .into(imgProfile);

                            // showing dot next to notifications label
                            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
                        }

                        /***
                         * Returns respected fragment that user
                         * selected from navigation menu
                         */
                        private void loadHomeFragment() {
                            // selecting appropriate nav menu item
                            selectNavMenu();

                            // set toolbar title
                            setToolbarTitle();

                            // if user select the current navigation menu again, don't do anything
                            // just close the navigation drawer
                            if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
                                drawer.closeDrawers();

                                // show or hide the fab button
                                //toggleFab();
                                return;
                            }

                            // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
                            // when switching between navigation menus
                            // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
                            // This effect can be seen in GMail app
                            Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // update the main content by replacing fragments
                                    HomeFragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                                   // FragmentTransaction replace = fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                                }
                            };

                            // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
                            if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                                mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
                            }

                            // show or hide the fab button
                          //  toggleFab();

                            //Closing drawer on item click
                            drawer.closeDrawers();

                            // refresh toolbar menu
                            invalidateOptionsMenu();
                        }

                        private HomeFragment getHomeFragment() {
                            switch (navItemIndex) {
                                case 0:
                                    // home
                                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                                    return homeFragment;
                                case 1:
                                    // profile

                                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                                    return profileFragment;
                                case 2:
                                    // movies fragment
                                    MoviesFragment moviesFragment = new MoviesFragment();
                                    return moviesFragment;
                                case 3:
                                    // notifications fragment
                                    NotificationFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                                    return notificationsFragment;

                                case 4:
                                    // settings fragment
                                    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                                    return settingsFragment;
                                default:
                                    return new HomeFragment();
                            }
                        }

                        private void setToolbarTitle() {
                            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(activityTitles[navItemIndex]);
                        }

                        private void selectNavMenu() {
                            navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
                        }

                        private void setUpNavigationView() {
                            //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
                            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                                // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
                                @Override
                                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                                    //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                                        //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                                        case R.id.nav_home:
                                            navItemIndex = 0;
                                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.nav_profile:

                                            Intent i3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,ProfileFragment.class);
                                            startActivity(i3);
                                            navItemIndex = 1;
                                          CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PROFILE;
                                            break;
                                       /* case R.id.nav_movies:
                                            navItemIndex = 2;
                                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                                            break;*/
                                        case R.id.nav_notifications:
                                            navItemIndex = 3;
                                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.nav_settings:
                                            navItemIndex = 4;
                                            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                                            break;
                                        case R.id.nav_about_us:
                                            // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUsActivity.class));
                                            drawer.closeDrawers();
                                            return true;
                                        /*case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                                            // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrivacyPolicyActivity.class));
                                            drawer.closeDrawers();
                                            return true;*/
                                        default:
                                            navItemIndex = 0;
                                    }

                                    //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                                    if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                        menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                    } else {
                                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                    }
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);

                                    loadHomeFragment();

                                    return true;
                                }
                            });


                            ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer,toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

                                @Override
                                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                                    // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                                }
                            };

                            //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
                            drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

                            //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
                            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onBackPressed() {
                            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return;
                            }else
                            {
                                super.onBackPressed();
                            }

                            // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
                            // when user is in other fragment than home
                            if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
                                // checking if user is on other navigation menu
                                // rather than home
                                if (navItemIndex != 0) {
                                    navItemIndex = 0;
                                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                                    loadHomeFragment();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }

                            super.onBackPressed();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

                            // show menu only when home fragment is selected
                            if (navItemIndex == 0) {
                                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                            }

                            // when fragment is notifications, load the menu created for notifications
                            if (navItemIndex == 3) {
                                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notifications, menu);
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                            int id = item.getItemId();

                            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                            if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logout user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return true;
                            }

                            // user is in notifications fragment
                            // and selected 'Mark all as Read'
                            if (id == R.id.action_mark_all_read) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All notifications marked as read!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }



                            // user is in notifications fragment
                            // and selected 'Clear All'
                            if (id == R.id.action_clear_notifications) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clear all notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);

                            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                        }

                        // show or hide the fab
                       /* private void toggleFab() {
                            if (navItemIndex == 0)
                                fab.show();
                            else
                                fab.hide();
                        }
                    */



                        @Override
                        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                        }


                        public void onSectionAttached(Object argSectionNumber) {
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: post your fragment's xml

Answer (score 0):

In that fragment's xml ,in parent layout set white background using below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="No data received" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thankyou but it didnt worked. I have constraint layout as parent layout

Comment: Can u post your xml?

Comment: please see xml above

Comment: Take height and width of ScrollView as match_parent and set background as #FFF .